# Good pairing for Phenomena font?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, web-fonts, font-pairing

I'm trying to find a good pairing for the main font that I've chosen for a website, namely the [Phenomena](http://www.fontfabric.com/phenomena-font/) font from Fontfabric:

[image]

I'm using this font for the Headings and Titles, and I'm trying to find a good match for the body copy text. It must be said that the Phenomena family is fairly complete, and by mixing different weights and sizes, even using the same font for the copy doesn't give a bad result:

[image]

Anyway, it seems to me that in terms of readability, this font gives its better on heading and not on copy text, and probably there is not enough contrast (but this is just my opinion, I may be wrong).

Some other alternatives that I've considered are the "standard" [Noto Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Noto+Sans/):

[image]

and [Roboto Slab](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Slab/):

[image]

The best result so far seems to be the pairing with a Slab font, that compliments fairly well IMHO with the geometric vibe of Phenomena.

What do you guys think of these pairings? What is the one that you think works best? **And of course, I'm entirely open to new suggestions, not limited to these trials by me.**

If you want to suggest new fonts besides the ones that I've mentioned here, please limit the choice to free-for-commercial-use ones (not necessarily present on Google Fonts). Thank you.

Comment: Of the samples you've provided, Noto Sans has the best legibility for body text. It also isn't competing with the header as much. Maybe bump it up against some traditional sans fonts like Arial, Futura, or Helvetica just to rule out any obvious solutions. Just my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, after some more trials I'm convinced too that the body text need a simple font. Trying out more combinations with Noto and Muli

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Lato, Noto, Roboto or something similar. Sans serif. Certainly not serif and not condensed for body text.